# Field calculator problem

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have an issue withe the field calculator. It is impossible for me to multiplicate 2 columns (area * KZ). The result is always "0". I used the formula area * KZ....is this the right formula? [LINK to shape file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/40q7f07q5rnp81h/TMP.zip)
Here the steps I did:

1. Using the "advanced python field calculator" to replace the strings "A"into 1, "B" into 2, "C" into 3 and so on
2. Using the field calculator (processing plugin) with the formula KZ * area without success

[image: screenshot field calculator]

Comment: There is no .dbf in your zipfile, so there is no attributes linked with your shapefile

Comment: Try now again, please.

Comment: The .prj file claims to be WGS84, but the extent is something in meters.

Comment: Is this aproblem for the calculator?

Comment: I tryed with the processor Field Calculator and it worked. 'area' * 'KZ'

Comment: You tried it withe the quatation marks (')? I tried it but without success. I always get 0 as result.

Comment: There is something you are doing wrong... when you click run, do you have a new temporary layer in output?

Comment: Yes I do have a new temp output shape. Is that a problem?

Comment: It is not a problem, it's normal. I am sorry I cant help you. I am doing the same thing here with your shapefile and it is working.

Comment: Here I have a little presentation where you see all the steps I did. Can you see any mistakes? I just tried to culculate the KZ*2.      https://www.dropbox.com/s/nzjavd2aw2pzvtg/Pr%C3%A4sentation1.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Quote your fields like this:

```
'area' * 'KZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your columns are of type `integer` or `real`.

In many cases they are of type string, which requires to change the format using `toint()` or `toreal()` functions in field calculator.

Comment: Sorry, I sent you an old file with a string type. I also tried it (processing - field calculator) with a real type...without success.

Answer (score 0):

I tryed to do what you want with your shapefile in QGIS

1. I created a new real (float) field (length: 20 precision: 10)
2. I used the Field Calculator with this command:  "area"  *  "KZ"

Results:

[image]

Comment: I tried it withe the "processing" field calculator, because I want to use it later in a model. But it doesnt work.

Comment: Please edit your question to enumerate all steps you are doing in details